# CAppModule vs CAtlExeModuleT , getting the application message loop

Tags: c++, winapi, atl, wtl

I am trying to get the message loop from a ATL::CAppModule in my project, there seems to be none, so:

- I've tried defining CAppModule, with `extern CAppModule _Module;` in `"stdafx.h"` and `CAppModule _Module;` in my *.cpp file*,  it compiles, linkes and at the perform registration step I get an assertion in `atlbase.h` here
  `ATLASSERT(_pAtlModule == NULL);`
  which means that the CAppModule has already been declared.

But I can't seem to find another CAppModule instantiation, instead I see a CAtlExeModuleT instantiation (it is not my code..).

now.. from what I've searched I haven t found a way to get the message loop from a CAtlExeModuleT object. Are they different things or am I missing something?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There is a mix of issues here. `CAppModule` is a WTL class. `_pAtlModule` is static/global ATL variable that points to module singleton class.

You cannot fix ATL `_pAtlModule` problem with WTL `CAppModule` because the two are unrelated (atlthough have certain similarity between).

To fix the `_pAtlModule` problem you need an ATL module instance. The simplest is to add `CComModule` static:

```
CComModule _Module; // <-- Here you go

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
  //...
```

Because `CComModule` itself is here for backward compatibility only, it would be the better to use `CAtlExeModuleT` (and friends) instead, however WTL will not work this way because WTL's `CAppModule` inherits from `CComModule`. The global instance of `CAppModule` will also be the instance for ATL `CComModule`:

```
CAppModule _Module;

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    // ...
    _Module.Init(...
    CMessageLoop MessageLoop;
    _Module.AddMessageLoop(&MessageLoop);
    // ...
```

and then later on some application object:

```
CMessageLoop* pMessageLoop = _Module.GetMessageLoop();
```

the `GetMessageLoop` call will retrieve the message loop you added earlier.

Having this ATL/WTL issue resolved, you can move on to the [WTL message loop thing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17865804/wtl-accelerator-pretranslatemessagemsg-pmsg-not-getting-called), where you expect `PreTranslateMessage` to be called on modal dialog message loop and it won't be called there because it is not expected to work this way (`CMessageLoop` calls message filter chain, and modal dialog's loop don't).

Comment: CModule does not have GetMessageLoop, how I am supposed to get the message loop using CAtlExeModule ? I have already done your "better" aproach, how do I now get the message loop

Comment: I don't see your real code and I don't understand that is going on. `CMessageLoop` map is per-thread, and you cannot get an instance you never added earlier on the same thread.

Comment: OK, thank you very much and sorry for flooding with comments, neighbour.