# _pAtlModule pointer is null when i try to CreateInstance using the CComObject function

Tags: c++, com, atl

I am working on the OPC(OLE process Control)Client program,with the asynchronous CALLBACK methods to get data from PLC using the KepServer.But I encountered the issue:

```
CComObject<COPCDataCallback>* pCOPCDataCallback;    // Pointer to Callback Object

// Create Instance of Callback Object using an ATL template
CComObject<COPCDataCallback>::CreateInstance(&pCOPCDataCallback);
```

and then it stopped at here:

```
_pAtlModule->Lock();
```

this is in the atlcom.h

any ideas of how to solve this issue?

Answer (score 7):

When you are using [ATL classes](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x1c35cc3) like `CComObject`, it is assumed that you have an ATL project, with "ATL module" class defined in it, such as [`CAtlExeModuleT`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d13b538z) based for EXE application.

With no module class/instance defined, there is no initialization of global internal `_pAtlModule` variable and hence the problem. You need to add the module class.

One of the ways to add ATL support is using IDE, typically if your existing project is MFC-based:

- [Adding ATL support to existing mfc application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8046786/adding-atl-support-to-existing-mfc-application)
- [How to get ATL support into an existing Windows application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25164042/how-to-get-atl-support-into-an-existing-windows-application)

Another way is to add `CAppModule` instance, if your project is using WTL:

- [CAppModule vs CAtlExeModuleT , getting the application message loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17884290/cappmodule-vs-catlexemodulet-getting-the-application-message-loop/17884618#17884618)

Then third way is to create a new clean ATL project of matching type (EXE or DLL) using Visual Studio wizard, and to check the code around `CAtlDllModuleT` or `CAtlExeModuleT` classes, then to duplicate that in your existing project.

Comment: @lyang You should mark this as the solution. It gives points to the person who answered.

Comment: It seems that you can also use CComObjectNoLock but that doesn't lock the module. Use CComCreator then to create the object (but this increments the reference count contrary to CComObject::CreateInstance).